# The following assertion was thrown building Navigator

Tags: flutter, dart

Can I navigate to another widget when the first one is being built?

```
The following assertion was thrown building Navigator-[GlobalObjectKey<NavigatorState> _WidgetsAppState#1d8fb](dirty, state: NavigatorState#999bc(tickers: tracking 2 tickers)):
```

im trying to demonstrate how to navigate from one screen to another without pressing any buttons, i mean if im at a certain screen it will load the other screen after a few seconds without me doing anything, however when i put the navigator outside the build method and call it with initState it gives me an error.
heres my code

```
 class Screen0 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Screen0State createState() => _Screen0State();
}

class _Screen0State extends State<Screen0> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    changeScreen();
    super.initState();
  }

  void changeScreen() {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page');
    }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}


--------------------- my other screen -----------------------------
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i fixed it using this code for the navigator in the changeScreen method:

```
Future(() {
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CityScreen()));
      });
```

thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to understand a little bit more about the lifecycle of a widget in Flutter. When the initState is called the framework is busy rendering the widget to the widgets tree. All its doing in the initState is that its collecting information that might be needed to render the widgets in a certain way.

What you are doing by calling `changeScreen()` in the initState is, you are telling flutter to build another widget when its already building one. Which gives an error.

Only when the first widget is built, you can Navigate to(or Build) another widget.

Now let's talk about how you can accomplish what you are trying to do.

You want to navigate to another widget after a fraction of second, once the main screen is built.

You need to let flutter render its main widget (whose initState you want to edit) and only then tell it to navigate to another widget.

Change your `changeScreen()` function like this:

```
  changeRoute() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
      );
    });
  }
```

What happens here, is that the event loop waits for 1 second (defined by us in the Future.delayed method) and then everything in `changeScreen()` happens. By the end of that 1 second, flutter renders its main widget and looks for whats left. Whats left? our `changeScreen()`!!

Hence, right after one second. The screen Navigates.

PS: This answer might be debatable as we don't know how much time flutter will take to render the main widget. If it takes more than one second (very rare), then the error will persist.

Comment: hello thank you so much for your explanation what you say here is what i found as an answer not long ago, and fixed my code like this:                                                      void changeScreen() {
    Future(() {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>
                  MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page')));
    });
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 main()=>runApp(MyApp());

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => Screen0(),
        '/home': (context) => MyHomePage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

 class Screen0 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Screen0State createState() => _Screen0State();
}

class _Screen0State extends State<Screen0> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    changeScreen();
    super.initState();
  }

  void changeScreen() {
      // The delay fixes it
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 5000)).then((_) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Text('First Screen'),
    ),
    );
  }
}


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(''),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

check out this, it might hep you out.

let me know if it works

Thanks.

Comment: thankyou so much i put the navigator in a Future method and it worked!